# How to request "Facebook email on authentication"

Tags: facebook, authentication

In my solution I need user email after sign up / sign in. Therefore I need to guaratee get email everytime.

What am I thinking is - set required parameter "email" on "Facebook Authentication" process.

Problem is I don't see any settings [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com) in console or documentation.

Q can anybody help how it solve?

Comment: You can't. You need to handle the case when the user choose not to give you their email or if they don't have an email

Comment: @WizKid thx - I saw many apps that have on this process this item email default checked and disable to uncheck - so I think there is somewhere solution.

Comment: No there is no solution

Comment: OK @WizKid thx for response.

Comment: When you saw apps doing it, that was likely a while ago ... it was possible in early API versions, but when the mobile platform started to gain tracking, they removed it, because most users signing up using their mobile do not even have an email address on file with Facebook.

Comment: OK @CBroe thx for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @WizKid @CBroe response I made workaround.

When user don't have email we ask for it again. :-)

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
 &client_id={{client_id}}
 &scope=email
 &redirect_uri={{redirect_uri}}
 &response_type=code
 &state={{state}}
 &auth_type=rerequest
```